# Deep equal using promises in Chai.js (testing)

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

I'm using Chai for my test and I want to deep compare the returned object from a promise.

I tried this approach:

```
expect(promise).to.eventually.eql(object)
expect(promise).deep.equals(object)
expect(promise).should.eventually.equal(object)
```

But it does not work. I checked many other samples but none of them works. This is what I'm getting:

> AssertionError: Unspecified AssertionError

Does anyone experienced something similar?

(By the way, the "object" contains an array of objects...)

Comment: Can you post a complete mocha test that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply combine the `eventually`(which is from `chai-as-promised`?) and the `deep`.

```
expect(promise).to.eventually.deep.equal(object)
```